# How to lock table view scrolling while at beginning and at end of a table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

When I am at the beginning I don't want the table view to scroll upward anymore.

Similarly when I'm at the end of list I don't want to scroll down anymore.

Although both the times it can be dragged a little and then it comes back to the original position.

`self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;`is only good as long as the list size doesn't surpass the screen size.

Comment: hmm.. so that called bounce property. Got it.

Answer (score 4):

Try giving

`self.tableView.bounces = NO;`

Answer (score 1):

Through the Interface Builder in Storyboard Just uncheck the `Bounce` Option for `UITableView` will remove bounce for both direction or if you want for one direction just uncheck one of them.

[image: Just Uncheck the <code>Bounce</code> Option]